# Pandas groupby winsorized mean

Tags: python, pandas

The normal groupby mean is easy:

```
df.groupby(['col_a','col_b']).mean()[col_i_want]
```

However, if i want to apply a winsorized mean (default limits of 0.05 and 0.95) which is equivalent to clipping the dataset then performing a mean, there suddenly seems to be no easy way to do it? I would have to:

```
winsorized_mean = []
col_i_want = 'col_c'
for entry in df['col_a'].unique():
    for entry2 in df['col_b'].unique():
        sub_df = df[(df['col_a'] == entry) & (df['col_b'] == entry2)]
        m = sub_df[col_to_groupby].clip(lower=0.05,upper=0.95).mean()
        winsorized_mean.append([entry,entry2,m])
```

Is there a function I'm not aware of to do this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [scipy.stats.trim_mean](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.trim_mean.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import trim_mean

# label 'a' will exhibit different means depending on trimming
label = ['a'] * 20 + ['b'] * 80 + ['c'] * 400 + ['a'] * 100

data = list(range(100)) + list(range(500, 1000))

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': label, 'data': data})

grouped = df.groupby('label')

# trim 5% off both ends
print(grouped.apply(stats.trim_mean, .05))

# trim 10% off both ends
print(grouped.apply(stats.trim_mean, .1))
```

Comment: Had to edit it to `grouped = df.groupby([col_a,col_b])[col_i_want]` to get it to work but great! thanks!